# "What do you think" + Indirect question?

Tags: word-order, questions, indirect-question

I ran into this sentence

-*What **do** you think **are** the advantages and disadvantages of city life?*

which appeared as rubric in *[Cambridge Vocabulary For Advanced](http://assets.cambridge.org/97805211/82195/excerpt/9780521182195_excerpt.pdf)* (Unit 1, p12), written by Haines Simon.

I was wondering if someone can clarify why in this particular phrase "What do you think" is followed by a direct question rather than an indirect question such as "What **do** you think the advantages and disadvantages of city life **are**?" .

Allegedly, the grammatical structure should be "Wh- direct question + indirect question ?" as in the case of "What do you think these objects are?" or "What do you think their jobs are?".

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: "What are the advantages and disadvantages of city life?"

Comment: We all slip up, even an English language text book writer. It might do with  the length of the subject, so the speaker uses the more familiar pattern for questions, i.e. inverting the auxiliary (are) with the subject (the advantages and disadvantages of city life).

Comment: We're gonna get these allegators. // << What, do you think, are these objects? >> probably needs the commas to offset the almost speech-tag analogue, modal / conversational lubricant parenthetical pragmatic marker _do you think_ here (the matrix sentence being the question << What are these objects? >>  The commas become less necessary and in fact clunky with the weightier _are the advantages and disadvantages of city life?_ (but are still an option, if dramatic pauses are preferred).

Comment: I think @Mari-Lou has it right here. Placing _are_ after a long subject contravenes the principle of "end-weight". It's even more apparent if the subject is extended: _What do you think the advantages and disadvantages of city life in these difficult times are?_ In fact, I would not regard the original sentence as an error.

Comment: Here, 'do you think' has a parenthetical meaning. It should have two commas like "What,  do you think, are the advantages and disadvantages of city life?"

Comment: Dear Edwin Ashworth, following your train of thought, shall we say then: "could you tell me what ARE the best advantages and the worst disadvantages of countryside life for parents with little children at school age?",  without placing "ARE" at the end?

Comment: Terminal 'are' would be ludicrous with this one. I'd find the 'uninverted' remedy awkward here, though; in conversation. So (if I felt the hedging intro better) I'd use "Can I ask you this: what would you say are the...

Answer (score 4):

> *What do you think are the advantages and disadvantages of city life?*

This is a perfectly grammatical and colloquial sentence. The analysis given in the question

> "*What do you think* is followed by a direct question"

is wrong: *are the advantages and disadvantages of city life* is not a direct question. It's not a question at all; it's not even a complete clause -- no subject. It's just a verb phrase.  In fact, it's the verb phrase in the question

- *What are the advantages and disadvantages of city life?*

which is what is being asked here. The *do you think* part is non-informational; how else would anybody answer except what they think?

The actual syntax is a result of the *Wh*-Question Formation rule, which can yank a *Wh*-word from almost anywhere in a sentence and stick it at the front of a question, after inverting the subject and first auxiliary of the question, like a *Yes/No* question.

This happens in stages, starting with the original non-question structure, with an unspecified argument that'll become the *Wh*-word. Most of these intermediate structures are ungrammatical (they're not finished) but I'll include them without question marks to illustrate the steps in the derivation.  Here's the original structure that will result in the question:

- *You think `Unspec` are the advantages and disadvantages of city life*

To make a *Wh*-question out of this, you start by replacing the `Unspec` with the appropriate *Wh*-word:

- *You think **what** are the advantages and disadvantages of city life*

Then make a *Yes/No* question by inverting subject (*you*) and first auxiliary.

> **But**, since *You think* has no auxiliary, *Do*-Support applies, and a new shiny auxiliary comes out of the slot and takes the tense morpheme, which is Zero in all cases so there's no change except adding *do* as an auxiliary:

- ***You do** think what are the advantages and disadvantages of city life*

and then inverting it with *you*:

- ***Do you** think what are the advantages and disadvantages of city life*

We're almost there now; the last step in *Wh*-Question Formation is to move the *Wh*-word *what* to the front, from wherever it was in the original:

- ***What** do you think ___ are the the advantages and disadvantages of city life?*

The hole in the sentence where the *what* came from is of course not audible. But it does mark a clause boundary; it's just that the subject of the clause has been moved up and out, giving the impression that *what do you think* is a constituent (it isn't, in this sentence) and that *are the advantages ...* is a question (as noted, it isn't).

Language is not a matter of words on a string like beads; there are constructions and they can change, by rule.

Comment: "Where do you think the nearest poll site is?" OR should I say "Where do you think is the nearest poll site?"

Comment: They are both grammatical; just questions of two versions of a symmetric clause with an indefinite locative: _The nearest poll site is `Indef Loc`_ versus _`Indef Loc` is the nearest poll site_.  Each one produces a different output when run through the *Wh*-Question Formation rule.

Comment: Your movement analysis starts with your **original structure**: _You think <Unspec> are the advantages and disadvantages of city life_, where you somehow assume that <Unspec> is the subject of the content clause. What is that assumption based on? What's stopping you to assume that the subject of the content clause is _the advantages and disadvantages of city life_? Would your **original structure** be different if you were to analyze the movement of _What do you think they are?_?

Comment: @JohnLawler Please have a look at the above comment of mine. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I just heard back from Editorial department in Cambridge University Press and this is what they respond:

"Sometimes in indirect questions where the subject is a very long phrase, we can reverse the order of the subject (the advantages and disadvantages of city life) and the verb (are) in order to make the question less unwieldy and more balanced."

In all honesty, I´m quite satisfied with the explanation.

Comment: I'm not sure that I'd agree that 'the advantages and disadvantages of city life' is long enough to qualify; I'd read this sentence with pauses, requiring commas: 'What, do you think, are the advantages and disadvantages of city life?' The 'do you think' hardly adds any semantic content; it's rather a conversational filler, making the question appear less stark (ie having a pragmatic role). 'What, do you think, are these?' works similarly, but certainly wouldn't without the commas.

Comment: Certainly, you`ve made your point, the actual fact is the original question was written without any comma, though. Cheers!