# What do you think + indirect question. Part 2

Tags: indirect-question

["What do you think" + Indirect question?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/548354/what-do-you-think-indirect-question/548401?noredirect=1#comment1348140_548401)

Dear John Lawler, should I infer from your detailed analysis that "what do you think..." at times does not involve using the indirect question structure? I tend to believe it would contradict the basic grammar rule for any indirect question regarding the placement of the main verb. Following your explaination, would you say in proper English: "what do you think does that strange symbol represent?" in lieu of "what do you think that strange symbol represents?". Besides, if I suggest, in accordance with your view, "Could you tell me what are the advantages and disavantages of city life?", should this sentence really be taken as grammatical? I`m afraid I cannot see eye to eye with you. Thanks

Comment: Please, anyone else is welcome to comment on this, feel free to do so! thanks

Comment: "What do you think that strange symbol represents? is a main clause interrogative and thus does not contain a subordinate interrogative (your indirect question). It's fine. For your other question, "Could you tell me [what are the advantages and disadvantages of city life]" is fine, as is "Could you tell me [what the advantages and disadvantages of city life are]". They both contain a subordinate interrogative, bracketed.

Comment: Thanks Bill for your participation and reply. I fully agree with the sentence "could you tell me, what are the advantage and disadvantages of city life?" as long as the comma is inserted right after "...tell me,". As to the first sentence, I share your opinion which is definitely opposite to John Lawler`s stand, though. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I just heard back from Editorial department in Cambridge University Press and this is what they respond:

"Sometimes in indirect questions where the subject is a very long phrase, we can reverse the order of the subject (the advantages and disadvantages of city life) and the verb (are) in order to make the question less unwieldy and more balanced."

In all honesty, I´m quite satisfied with the explanation.